# About Slick 3.0.0, Why insert with exist PK don't throw any error?

Tags: scala, slick

Hi I'm so confuse on Slick 3, I have create simple insert. 
If I have insert new PK, It's working well but when I tried insert an exist PK, Slick don't throw any error and future.isCompleted is still return true. 
So What wrong of my code?

```
val db = Database.forConfig("db")
val future = {
  try {
    val insert = DBIO.seq(
      subscribers += subscriber
    )
    db.run(insert.transactionally)
  } finally db.close
}
return if (future.isCompleted) return Some(subscriber) else None
```

Solved: I Just have to Await the result.

```
val db = Database.forConfig("db")
val isCompleted = {
  val f = db.run((subscribers += subscriber).transactionally)
  try {
    Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
    true
  } catch {
    case _ => false
  } finally db.close
}
return if (isCompleted) return Some(subscriber) else None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your code does not wait till the future `db.run(insert.transactionally)` finishes. You create the future and then immediately close the db.

Comment: I have add a detail, So why when I have inserted a new PK, Is it working fine?